# Different output than expected

Tags: python

I just started programming and right now I'm stuck with a problem. I'm wondering how if functions really work.

```
a = [ 20.0, 8.0, 2.5 ]
b = 4
if b > len(a): 
    r = 2*b
r = b
```

I expected the output of 8, but the actual output is 4. How come? Because 4 > 3 and that should execute the if statement right?

Comment: `r` is 8 after the execution of the if statement, but then you reassign `r` with `b`, which is 4.

Comment: `a = [ 20.0, 8.0, 2.5 ]
b = 4
if b > len(a): 
    r = 2*b
print(r)
r = b
print(r)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you do not have an `else` statement which should be executed if your condition `if b > len(a)` is not `True`. So in your code, the `if` statement is first executed, the value of `r` becomes twice of `b` (`r` becomes 8) but then you come out of the `if` statement and **again** reassign `b` to `r` which is why your `r` becomes 4 again. I hope the concept is clear now.

The correct way would be

```
a = [ 20.0, 8.0, 2.5 ]
b = 4

if b > len(a):
     r = 2*b
else:
     r = b
```

Comment: Sorry for my bad English, I forgot to mention it is a homework problem and the output that it gives is 4 but I thought it would give the output of 8. Why is the output 4 and not 8 when I use the code above?

Comment: Did you read my answer? I have explained why the output was 4 and not 8. If you run the code I provided, the output will be 8 as desired.

Comment: My bad, I read it again and now I understand the concept. Thank you very much!